# Multiple Columns Text Table Creations

Tags: tables, multicolumn, text

Since 2 days I have been trying to create the kind of table in the image below. Can you help me to make this.[image]

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436)  Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) that shows what you tried so far.

Comment: Please also add some clarifications to your question. Are the "description"  and "references"  parts also part of the table or just the "input", "output", "advantages"  and "disadvantages"  parts?

Answer (score 1):

As starting point:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs, tabularx}
\usepackage{iwona}  %   nice sans serif fonts
\usepackage{lipsum} % generate dummy text filler

\begin{document}
    \begin{table}[htbp]
\renewcommand\tabularxcolumn[1]{m{#1}}
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{@{} X X @{}}
    \toprule
\hfil INPUT       &\hfil   OUTPUT       
    \cmidrule(r){1-1}\cmidrule(l){2-2}
\lipsum[11]       &   \lipsum[12]       \\
    \midrule
\hfil ADVANTAGES  &\hfil DISADVANTAGES   \\
    \cmidrule(r){1-1}\cmidrule(l){2-2}
\lipsum[12] &   \lipsum[11]     \\
    \bottomrule
\end{tabularx}
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```